# How do I convert HTML code into a JavaScript String variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering how I can convert my HTML code that has been garbed with my document.getElementById("landornot") function and convert it into a string. For example right now when I console.log it I get `<li class="listing-property-type" id="landornot"><span class="label">Property Type: </span><a href="https://axisutahdev.wpengine.com/property-types/land/" rel="tag">Land</a></li>`

What I want is it to be in a string so it should look like this `'<li class="listing-property-type" id="landornot"><span class="label">Property Type: </span><a href="https://axisutahdev.wpengine.com/property-types/land/" rel="tag">Land</a></li>'`

I haven't been able to find any helpful resource online any help would be appreciated.

My Code:

```
<script>
    window.onload = (event) => {
        const land = document.getElementById("landornot");
        console.log(land);
        
        if (land === '<li class="listing-property-type" id="landornot"><span class="label">Property Type: </span><a href="https://axisutahdev.wpengine.com/property-types/land/" rel="tag">Land</a></li>') {
            console.log('Right Page')
        } else {
            console.log('Wrong Page')
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: `newvar = oldvariable.toString()`

Comment: Why would you want to compare an element via its serialization? This will just result in very fragile code. What exactly is this `if` statement supposed to check? If you want to check if the URL of the link is the one with `property-types/land`, why not simply check `if(document.querySelector("#landornot a[rel='tag'][href$='property-types/land/']"))` or something similar? This seemt to be an [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/289905).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the .outerHTML property? E.g. `console.log(land.outerHTML);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script>
        window.onload = (event) => {
            const land = document.getElementById("landornot");
            land = land.outerHTML;
            console.log(land);
            
            if (land === '<li class="listing-property-type" id="landornot"><span class="label">Property Type: </span><a href="https://axisutahdev.wpengine.com/property-types/land/" rel="tag">Land</a></li>') {
                console.log('Right Page')
            } else {
                console.log('Wrong Page')
            }
        };
    </script>
```

you need **element.outerHTML**

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use the built in function:
Tostring()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).